# I can't open tomcat

Tags: tomcat, windows-services

I'm using Tomcat 5.5 on Windows Vista. When I exit my tomcat, I can't run it again.

> Access is denied. Unable to open the
>   service 'Tomcat5'

Why is that so? What can I do to make it work again? Must I reinstall everytime I exit tomcat?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing that error message? Please give more detail in the question - state *exactly* what you're doing.

Comment: Can you check that the tomcat process isn't running anymore? Or are you running tomcat as a service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you mean that you are exiting tomcat monitor and not actually tomcat service ... tomcat servicer is managed by windows SCM and monitor just lets you start and stop service

even though you exit tomcat monitor you can always start and stop service from either services.msc MMC snap-in or you can always start and stop service from command line

to start and stop service from command line do the following:

from elevated command prompt:
net start tomcat5 (to start the service)
net stop tomcat5 (to stop the service)
sc query tomcat5 (to query the status of tomcat)

now to solve your problem ... run the tomcat manager as administrator (right click)

Answer (score 2):

A permanent fix is to right-click the short-cut, click on 'Properties', click the 'Shortcut' tab, click the 'Advanced...' button, then check the box "Run as administrator".